# "Custom" IdentityServer Implemention and EntityFrameworkStore Removal Inquiry

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, .net-5

Good Morning,

I have a new Blazor project where we are utilizing IdentityServer for individual user management. Out of the box, this is fine and works without issue, even with the extra fields, claims, and such that we've added.

My dilemma, at this point (early) in the project, is the application's server architecture:

- DMZ Web Server
- Internal API
- Internal DB

All database calls need to flow through the internal API, this is where my issue is with the base implementation of IdentityServer, as it is using EF for database calls; these are occurring directly from the web server, but, they need to go through the internal API.

I've done a lot of reading on IdentityServer, JwT, etc.... But, I've found nothing regarding this specific issue of using another server for the user management, **something that is already built into the identityserver mechanics and can be implemented with a simple configuration**.

So, I tested out overriding some of the UserManger and SignInManager methods to point to the API server methods. On the API, It is utilizing the base UserManger and SignInManager objects and is then performing its base methods for saving, stores, code generation, etc. This works quite well so far, I just have a few more minor hurdles to clear regarding the token retrieval/storage methods, which should be a simple service to inject/override. There have been a couple other minor issues regarding the User object passed to the Api not jiving with the User object hosted in the Store, but, very easy to circumvent. Another issue is to override the Dispose method, but, at the moment, that isn't too much of an issue.

My final questions are these:

- **Is this is a somewhat typical setup, or, at least a valid solution?** Getting down to it, the overriding of the base classes on the the front end is a bit overkill, but, it does allow for far fewer code changes on all of the razor pages. Additionally, this implementation will likely be used in other apps, so, having other devs on the team just use this base class should aid in their development.
- **If this is a valid setup/idea, is there any way to turn off or kill the front-end's EntityFramework store?** In the constructor, I'm setting this.Store = null. For the time being, the errors raised help me to see where else I need to dig and fix things, but, once everything is running, I'd like to fully omit that piece of the implementation.

Thank you for any suggestions/advise, in advance.

Comment: Stop! Before you go on with your project using IdentityServer make sure you've read this article ( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-6-and-authentication-servers/#comments ) by Microsoft , and its accompanied comments. Personally, I'm done with IdentityServer.

Comment: Just switch to an authentication scheme using JWTs (it's built-in to the .NET 5 framework). You can then run any backend code for managing your access and auth tokens.